# Odd behaviour from custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

https://jsfiddle.net/dqx7kb91/1/

In this fiddle, I extracted a part of a project (I tried to simplify it as much as I could without breaking anything), used to manage search filters.
We have many different types of filters defined as an object like this:

```
filter = {
    name: "",
    initVal: 1, //default value for the filter,
    controlChip: ... // filter's chip component
    ...
}
```

the chip component are used to list all filters activated and to edit already activated filters (in this case remove the filter from the list of activated filters).

The filters are contained in an object handled by an unique container containing  a custom hook.

The problem is, let's say I set the 1st filter, then set the second and I decide to finally remove the first filter, both filters are removed. Everything is working fine apart from this.

What might be causing this ? It seems to me that in the custom hook useMap that I use, when I try to remove the filter, it doesn't take account of the actual current state but uses the state it was when I added the first filter (an empty object), so it tries to remove something from nothing and set the state to the result, an empty object.

How can I fix this ? Thank you

Comment: I checked your code, it was pretty messy (unreadable for me), use react devtools and try to debug your problem.

Comment: I agree with @DennisVash regarding readability. That said, you should include your code in your question - preferably in a code snippet.

Comment: I disagree with Chris. With a large amount of code like that, I'd much rather use CodeSandbox or jsfiddle. Much easier to diagnose a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is when you set your first filter (let's say #1) you're setting `map` that contains just filter 1. When you set filter #2 `map` contains filters #1 & #2. BUT... and here's the thing... your remove callback for filter #1 has map only containing #1, not #2. That's because your callback was set before you set filter #2. This would normally be solved because you're using hooks like useCallback, but the way you're implementing them (`createContainer(useFilters)`), you're creating separate hooks for each filter object.

I would simplify this into only one component and once it is working start extracting pieces one by one if you really need to.

I know this is a complete rewrite from what you had, but this works:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = React.useState({});

  // const get = React.useCallback(key => map[key], [map])

  const set = (key, entry) => {
    setMap({ ...map, [key]: entry });
  };

  const remove = key => {
    const {[key]: omit, ...rest} = map;
    setMap(rest);
  };

  // const reset = () => setMap({});

  const filters = [
    { name: 'filter1', value: 1 },
    { name: 'filter2', value: 2 },
  ];

    return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(map).map(key => (
        <button onClick={() => remove(key)}>
           REMOVE {key}
         </button>
       ))}
       <hr />
      {filters.map(({ name, value }) => (
        <button onClick={() => set(name, { value })}>
          SET {name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  )
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```